# Why are we inheriting here in Django?

Tags: django, metaclass

I am a beginner in Django, and I am almost done reading through *Django for Beginners* by William S. Vincent. In chapter 8, he goes over the custom user model and creates the following code for the forms needed:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ("age",)


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserChangeForm.Meta.fields
```

Why are we using class Meta here? And why is the first `class Meta` inheriting from `UserCreationForm`, but the second `class Meta` doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is why are we using class Meta here and why is the first class Meta inheriting from "UserCreationForm", but the second class Meta doesn't.

Likely that is a typo, it should be:

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):  # 🖘 inherit from the Meta innerclass
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('age',)
```

It is usually a good idea to *always* inerhit from the `Meta` of the superclass, since it will for example in this case [also include the `field_classes` attribute <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L106-L109):

> ```
> class Meta:
>     model = User
>     fields = ("username",)
>     field_classes = {"username": UsernameField}
> ```

It here thus adds a specific field class for username, not the default `CharField`. If we want that behavior to continue, then we will need to inherit this, otherwise our `Meta` has no such `field_classes` item, and it will thus "fallback" on a simple `CharField`.

The latter was better with a simple:

```
class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
```

since for modern versions of Django, it will make use of the `UsernameField` field class as well.